# Do WP_debug notices explain why my site runs so slow?

Tags: performance, debug, memory

When I enable `WP_DEBUG`, I get lots of the following kinds of notices (see below). Of course, I normally don't have the debugging turned on, but I'm wondering if these are a clue as to why it takes so long *before* my pages load. To be extra clear, my site is fine once the pages start loading (so it's NOT about loading big resources).

I'm also on a very fast dedicated server, running `mod_php`, so I'm pretty confident the server isn't the bottleneck. The slowness is almost definitely related to MySQL/PHP taking a long time, and I'm having trouble figuring out why. If these notices aren't useful, is there something else I can do to check this?

I installed the debug bar plugin and it's showing around 8.5MB of memory usage, which I think is fairly standard for a WP site. I'm not sure how to interpret the object cache data but I've included that also below.

**CLARIFICATION:**
I'm not suggesting that generating the debug log is slowing down the site, rather I'm wondering if these errors are the result of a problem that might be slowing down the site. The ones I understand don't appear to be relevant, but I don't recognize all of them.

Thanks in advance!

> Notice: load_plugin_textdomain was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.7 with no alternative available. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2714

> Notice: load_plugin_textdomain was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.7 with no alternative available. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2714

> Notice: Undefined property: FacebookWidgets::$pluginDirectory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/facebook-social-widgets/facebook-social-widgets.php on line 25

> Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/ipaper/ipaper.php on line 11

> Notice: Undefined index: updatelocalip in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-complete-backup/wp-complete-backup.php on line 32

> Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-custom-admin-bar/custom-admin-bar-functions.php on line 8

> Notice: register_sidebar_widget is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_sidebar_widget() instead. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2628

> Notice: register_widget_control is deprecated since version 2.8! Use wp_register_widget_control() instead. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2628

> Notice: automatic_feed_links is deprecated since version 3.0! Use add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' ) instead. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2628

> Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2748

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 243

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 270

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 274

> Notice: Undefined index: hl_twitter_cron in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/hl-twitter/functions.php on line 96

> Notice: load_plugin_textdomain was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.7 with no alternative available. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2714

[image]

Comment: I suppose this question would be a much better fit for the [support forums](http://wordpress.org/support/)

Comment: @Johannes Pille I don't see why so?..

Comment: Because @Rarst, I figured the question was about the particular notices posted. I appear to be mistaken and the question is about the meaning of such notices in general. Since that appears to be the case, my suggestion should be disregarded, I suppose.

Comment: @Johannes Pille actually it seems your impression was more correct, still this feels fine for me. Not that there is much to answer, other than how to approach performance troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, notices by themselves are not a performance issue and generating them typically doesn't take considerable resources (there are exceptions if you are replacing error handler - I seen it get slow because of larger output volume and conflicts with antivirus). Of course what they do indicate is potential issues with code quality, which is everything but good for robust performance.

You can try plugins such as [P3](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/p3-profiler/) for easy first look, but I would recommend to look into more generic PHP profilers, such as [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and [XHProf](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof) for serious troubleshooting.

Comment: I should have been more clear. I wasn't asking if generating the errors was slowing the site down. Rather, I'm wondering if these specific errors indicate problems that would slow the site down. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: @Emerson as above - the one conclusion that can be drawn from errors is that there is some crappy code involved. It has no direct relation to performance of the site. Old and bugged code can run fast, modern code without any notices can run slow.

Comment: If you're using Debian, you can follow this guide for integrating xhprof into wordpress https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2022/06/07/wordpress-xhprof/